# How can you specify the manifest.json to only support Outlook 2016 (specifically I don't want to support 2013)

Tags: office-js

My add-in is working great on Outlook 2016: Windows, Mac, OWA.  Some users are reporting problems on Outlook 2013.  I don't have Outlook 2013, so I'd prefer to just disable support.  Is there an option in the manifest to disable 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enable/disable support for a specific Outlook version or platform (or any Office application). Office Web Add-ins use a [Requirement Sets](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/office-add-in-requirement-sets) system to determine which add-ins a given host can support.

For Outlook, this is specified by [mailbox version](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets). Since Outlook 2013 and 2016 support the same mailbox versions (`1.4`), they support the same set of add-ins.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the quick response.  It would be great if MSFT provided a set of pre-built VMs with Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016, and ideally for Windows and Mac.  I know MSFT has partnered with BrowserStack to provide free MS Edge VMs for testing, so something similar would be great.  I know it's a stretch, but it would be of great value to us developers.

Comment: I agree, although this is far more complicated than Edge. You're not looking for simply a VM with Outlook on it, you'd also need a sever to connect it to. If you have MSDN, we provide a developer tenant specifically for this purpose. You can set up an entire O365 environment with up to 25 test users and build the VM's you need for clients with the licenses from MSDN.

Comment: Marc is correct though a small correction. Office 2016 has 2 versions, clickToRun and MSI, the MSI version supports version set 1.4 however ClickToRun supports 1.5 for build numbers >=16.0.7828. We are working on updating the documentation to reflect the same

Comment: The CTR vs MSI I learned the "fun" way.  RE: VMs - Totally agree it's not a simple process, but I'll still ask Santa to bring it for XMAS ;-).  Even without the server, just connecting to Exchange Online, with my Office365 accounts.